# Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission...PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-permissions

I'm getting this error when uploading an image on my hosting.

> Request for the permission of type 'System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' failed.

It's always worked before. The only thing that's changed is I had to delete the uploads folder and recreate it and set its permissions again. Could something have gone wrong there?

I've researched this issue and some people have suggested setting the trust level to full in your web.config file but none of them actually explain how to do this. The upload works locally, which is why I believe its a permissions issue on my hosting. I'm banging my head against the wall because I set the permissions of the Uploads folder to read/write and it's throwing the same error...should I do this for the whole application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure what the issue was, but it fixed itself. Possibly a delay in setting the permissions on the hosting side.